# How to format different characters in a UILabel's string differently?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsstring, format, uilabel

I have a UILabel with a dynamic string as the text property.  If I always want the first word to be underlined, do I need to separate labels and then try to line them up correctly?  Or could I subclass UILabel to have it do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `UIWebView` and render the text as HTML.

Comment: yeah just read that in the doc for uitextview.  never worked with html though.

Comment: is there a way to clip the frame of a uilabel so it's only as big as it needs to be for the string it shows?

Comment: For your purposes, it's easy: just wrap the first word with `<u></u>`, so in your code you would change "Your mother sews socks that smell" to "<u>Your</u> mother sews socks that smell", and then set the HTML text as the `text` property for your `UIWebView` (it might use some other property than `text` for this, though).

Comment: @marty: this link has some code for drawing text wherever: http://groups.google.com/group/iphonesdkdevelopment/browse_thread/thread/eb5e64dd9fb7fcea?pli=1   You're probably better off sticking with a single UIView and drawing the different kinds of text on it - lot easier than trying to lay out multiple views.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using the `textRectForBounds:limitedToNumberOfLines:` to find the dynamic start point of the word (minus some x coordinate pixels), and then took away the first letter of the uilabel with `stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:withString:`, and then added another uilabel with the beginning letter of the original label, just with different font.